# Rendimiento de un ArrayList vs POJO (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist

Mi consulta es acerca del rendimiento al momento de recorrer un ArrayList vs POJO, es decir, si tomo los datos de la base de datos y los cargo al ArrayList y luego a un POJO:

¿Es más eficiente (a nivel de procesamiento) recorrer el ArrayList (posición [0], [1], ...) o el POJO (pojo.nombre, pojo.apellido, ..)?

Ejemplo del recorrido del ArrayList:

```
private List<Object[]> _listaClientes = new ArrayList<Object[]>();//creo el arrayList
public void cargaClientes(){
    try{
        _listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
        //obtengo los datos de la base de datos a través de un DAO
        _listaClientes = ctrClientes.getData();

        //Recorro el arrayList:
        for(Object[] obj : _listaClientes){
            System.out.println(obj[0]);//cedula
            System.out.println(obj[1]);//nombre
            //...
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ejemplo del recorrido del POJO (Cliente):

```
private List<Cliente> listaClientes;
public void cargaClientes(){
try{
    //obtengo los datos de la base de datos a través de un DAO
    listaClientes = ctrClientes.getDataPojo();

    //Recorro el POJO
    Iterator<Cliente> itrCli = listaClientes.iterator();
    while(itrCli.hasNext()){
        Cliente cli = itrCli.next();
        System.out.println(cli.cedula);//cedula
        System.out.println(cli.nombre);//nombre
        //...
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Un array list de que tipo de objetos? ¿Podrías agregar un [mcve]?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, agregué los ejemplos con el tipo de arrayList y POJO, con ejemplos cada uno, espero se entienda mejor así.

Comment: En realidad también podrías realizar un ArrayList de Objetos. Me parece que la comparación no es similar.

Comment: @DavidDavila en lo personal lo mas natural es mas manejar los datos como una lista de objectos(POJOS).

Comment: Gracias @NathanRothschild por tu opinión.

Comment: Tal vez sería bueno que pusieras como los estás leyendo, me inclinaría a creer que `getDataPojo` tiene más código que `getData` y que en una situación real, harías algo con los objetos y no simplemente imprimirlos

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Creo que tu pregunta es irrespondible en el sentido de que el mismo término *rendimiento* por el que preguntas es relativo y depende de millones de contextos. En cualquier caso, yo mapearía los resultados a un POJO y me sumo al certero comentario de @RuslanLópez. Se trata de ampliar posibilidades, de reutilizar los objetos, de aplicar métodos adecuados según contextos diferentes pero usando siempre los mismos datos. Para poner un ejemplo sencillo: una app donde en ciertos contextos necesitas imprimir el nombre con letra más grande, ¿qué elegirías?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @A.Cedano investigando un poco más veo que al iterar un objeto, lo que se hace es instanciar a dicho objeto y mostrar sus valores en cada iteración del bucle, lo cual tiene un costo superior comparando con recorrer un arrayList; ya que a los elementos del arrayList accedes directamente. El ejemplo como tú lo has dicho, es relativo, por lo tanto habrá casos en los que sea mejor iterar un objeto y otros recorrer el arrayList